# Wrap input text?

Tags: forms

What is the best practice for whether or not to wrap input text if a user enters too much text to fit?

It seems to me having the text wrap would be best but this isn't the default browser behavior.

Comment: In what context is the user entering text? A form? The URL field in a browser?

Comment: Form inputs eg name, phone number, email, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to always have the field wide enough to display short fields like names, phone numbers, and emails, without the need to wrap the text to another line. Such fields will always have a technical constraint on their length imposed by the back end (data base field), and this will be quite conservative anyway for short fields (why set up a phone number field to varchar(10000)?), so you always know the maximum length.

Longer fields, such as free text comments should be wrapped on a multi-line text area.